# django PermissionRequiredMixin permission_required not working

Tags: python, django, permissions, mixins, user-permissions

Views.py

```
class templateList(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'accounts.template_all'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #view logic
        print(self.request.user.has_perms('accounts.template_all'))
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

accounts/models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # some fields here
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

        permissions = (
            ("template_all", "access to all templates"),
        )
```

ViewName.___mro____

```
(<class 'template.views.templateList'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateView'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>, <class 'object'>)
```

`self.request.user.has_perms('accounts.template_all')` in views.py returns the correct boolean value, however, `self.has_permission()` returns True every time. `permission_required` has no effect, and the user is still able to see the page even when the print returns false. `self.get_permission_required` alos returns the correct value. Help appreciated.

Comment: I think you should order the baseclasses differently: `class viewName(PermissionRequiredMixin, AccessMixin, generic.TemplateView)`. Right now the `TemplateView` overrides your `PermissionRequiredMixin`.

Comment: Your `print(..)` test does not pass a tuple to the `has_perms`, what happens if you call it like: `print(self.request.user.has_perms('accounts.action_all',))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short**: the `PermissionRequiredMixin` baseclass should be placed *before* the `TemplateView` baseclass, such that the MRO (Method Resolution Order) is correct, and dispatch points to the override of the `PermissionRequiredMixin`.

A `PermissionRequiredMixin` patches the `dispatch(..)` method (well it adds an extra check that looks if the user has the proper permissions). Here however you have placed the subclasses in an order that results in the fact that the `dispatch(..)` function is the one from the `View` class.

Indeed, if we take a look at the MRO, we see:

```
>>> ViewName.__mro__
(<class 'ViewName'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateView'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin'>, <class 'object'>)
```

and if we take a look at the method that is called when we call `.dispatch(..)`, we see:

```
>>> ViewName.dispatch
<function View.dispatch at 0x7f169e8f6620>
```

In order to let the mixin override the original `.dispatch(..)` function, we need to put it first in the base classes, like:

```
# PermissionRequiredMixin is put before TemplateView

class ViewName(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'accounts.action_all'
    # ...
```

We then see that:

```
>>> ViewName.__mro__
(<class 'ViewName'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateView'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> ViewName.dispatch
<function PermissionRequiredMixin.dispatch at 0x7f168b41d620>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that, however, this change has unfortunately not solved the issue.

Comment: Also, should the accessMixin be before templateView?

Comment: @RudraMutalik: no, since the accesview is already in the `PermissionRequiredView`. Django uses `self.request.user.has_perms(perms)`, with `perms` the `('accounts.action_all',)` here (so a tuple), are you sure that is working correctly?

Comment: @RudraMutalik: I've tested it locally, and it seems to work. Since you specified a `User` model yourself, perhaps there is something that is not working entirely correct?

Comment: `self.request.user.has_perms('accounts.action_all')` returns the correct value, so that seems to be working

Comment: @RudraMutalik: yes, but `has_perms` is given an iterable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms  not a single list.

Comment: same result when it is a tuple

Comment: @RudraMutalik: what is the output of your `ViewName.__mro__`?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: @RudraMutalik: the mixin also offers a function `self.has_permission()`, perhaps it can be useful to print the response in your view and check if it generates the correct response.

Comment: It seems not, It is returning True when has_perms is false

Comment: @RudraMutalik: well `has_permission` is implemented like http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.contrib.auth.mixins/PermissionRequiredMixin/ so that means that `self.get_permission_required()` is not working correctly, or `self.request.user.has_perms(perms)` is not. So I propose in order to debug this, that you try to "reproduce" this locally (as in printing the result of `self.get_permission_required()` etc.